# Hosting build documentation from a pull request on GutHub

Tags: python, github, documentation

I work on an open source project.
In order to facilitate the review of sphinx documentation changes in our Python source code, we’d love if we could somehow get the documentation generated and hosted somewhere for each pull request, like we already do with coveralls for our code coverage.

Pushing new commits would update the generated doc for that pull request. We’ll be soon be adding doc generation to our travis build to find sphinx errors, but doing a final visual review would still need to be done locally by pulling the branch and generating it locally.

Is there any GitHub app that offers to host a webpage generated on a pull request?

Answer (score 0):

2018: You can make your own GitHub repository serve pages with [`GitHub pages`](https://pages.github.com/).

If you generate your documentation in the `gh-pages` branch [or the `doc/` subfolder](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#publishing-your-github-pages-site-from-a-docs-folder-on-your-master-branch) of your main branch, you can have both your codebase, and your doc in the repo.

See for instance [lneuhaus/pyrpl issue 85](https://github.com/lneuhaus/pyrpl/issues/85), which illustrates how to automate [Sphinx for Python documentation](https://gisellezeno.com/tutorials/sphinx-for-python-documentation.html)

```
cd doc/sphinx
sphinx-apidoc -f -o source/ ../../pyrpl/
make html
```

You can automate that using [`Syntaf/travis-sphinx`](https://github.com/Syntaf/travis-sphinx):

> A standalone script for automated building and deploying of sphinx docs via travis-ci

---

Update Q4 2022: the [OP fronsacqc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1074536/fronsacqc) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52466922/hosting-build-documentation-from-a-pull-request-on-guthub/52484156?noredirect=1#comment131577669_52484156):

> We ended up pushing the documentation generated by the build on an S3 folder tagged with the static hosting flag, so now every build's documentation is hosted on S3 for a couple of days.

Comment: Hi, we're already using Github Pages to host our documentation from the master branch. What I was hoping is to host the documentation generated by a pull request so it could be reviewed before being merged to master and then pushed to Github Pages.

Comment: @fronsacqc Not sure if that is possible within the same repo: you would need a dedicated PR repo for that, where you accept your PR in a master branch and view them in the GitHub Pages associated to that dedicated repo. And then, upon review, merge that master branch of that dedicated repo to your actual target repo.

Comment: We ended up pushing the documentation generated by the build on an S3 folder tagged with the static hosting flag, so now every build's documentation is hosted on S3 for a couple of days.

Comment: @fronsacqc 3 years later, thank you for this update, much appreciated. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.